# Can I join a table with no association? (rails/sql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have these 3 classes:

```
class Factory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :machines
end

class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :factory, inverse_of: :machines
  has_many :assembly_jobs, inverse_of: :machines
end

class AssemblyJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :machines, inverse_of: :assembly_jobs
end
```

Schema

```
Factories
- id

Machines
- factory_id

AssemblyJobs
- machine_id
- start_time
- error_time
- finish_time
```

I want to be write a scope in `factory.rb` to return any factories that have any machines with assembly jobs with error_time. Is this possible or do  I need to add a factory_id column to assembly job and create a belongs_to association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join tables without an association by entering a custom join query in the `joins` method:

```
Model.joins("<CONDITIONS FOR JOIN>")
```

However, in your case, you should be able to scope Factories with machines having assembly jobs using the following query

```
Factory.joins(machines: :assembly_jobs)
```

This will create a nested INNER JOIN where only factories with one or more machines having one or more assembly job will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can join two tables without a association

Refrence Link :

http://mapopa.blogspot.in/2010/06/rails-tip-joins-without-associations.html